# Case cases in Clojure

Tags: clojure, conditional-statements, case

Besides the constant time dispatch of `case`, what could be other points leading me to use `case` instead of `cond` `condp`?

Comment: +1 for the question. In my scenario where a lot of string comparison is involved, I found using `condp` is significantly faster than using `case`, which doesn't make sense. I suspect it to be attributed to optimization flags, though.

Comment: @Davyzhu Interesting. How many cases did you have in your condition(s)?

Comment: @Elogent I tested with instrumentation level profiling, and the number of conditions range from 3 to around 10. All of them, even the case with 10 branches, `condp` performs better than `case`.

Comment: @Davyzhu Do strings need their hash values calculated? If so, the cost  of `case` would have a component proportional to the length of the string. Might that be why `case` is slower than `condp`?

Comment: `case` is not constant time.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/case

Comment: @Thumbnail I doubt so... My strings are mostly short, less than 10 characters.

Comment: @AmirTeymuri What are you trying to say? Believe me, it's not constant time.

Comment: (or study the impl, which I did)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Assuming that you really are dealing with compile-time constants, `case` semantically conveys the nature of your condition better than `cond` or `condp`.
2. `case` is more concise than `cond` or `condp`.

Example:

```
(cond
  (= foo 1) :one
  (= foo 2) :two
  (= foo 3) :three)

(condp = foo
  1 :one
  2 :two
  3 :three)

(case foo
  1 :one
  2 :two
  3 :three)
```

I can't comment on any performance aspects, but as always, that should be the least of your considerations.

Answer (score 3):

Even where it's slower, `case` is often more expressive than `if`:

```
(defn fact [n]
  (case n
    0 1
    (* n (fact (dec n)))))
```

... reads better than

```
(defn fact [n]
  (if (zero? n) 1
    (* n (fact (dec n)))))
```

This is a matter of taste, but the `case` phrase is one form shorter.

Comment: very nice `fact`! by the way what do you mean by more expressive? is shortness of forms and elegance for the eyes the main differences from those forms which are less beautiful? and from your case-fact i can say that the only form gets evaluated in `case` is the last *default* form?

Comment: @AmirTeymuri Yes and no. On the first point, elegance promotes understanding by definition, I think. On the second point, the algorithm is properly recursive, so slow and limited to ~10K. And it blows up with stack overflow long before that: at 21 (replace `*` with `*'` to cure this). The default form is evaluated on every call but the deepest. Negative or zero arguments also overflow the stack. So it's a fairly shoddy algorithm, just for illustration.

Comment: @Thumbnail Indeed; I would probably implement it as `(apply *' (range 1 (inc n)))`.